# Android - The 3-dot dropdown menus does not appears if the device has a menu hardware button

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

I noticed that if you are using the actionbar with a device that has a "menu" hardware button, the 3-dot dropdown menus does not shows off. So in my app i have this menu layout:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
     />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_credits"
    android:title="@string/action_credits"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    />
<item android:title="@string/action_project"
        android:id="@+id/action_project"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    />
</menu>
```

If i try my app in a device without the hardware menu button, then the 3-dots appear in the action bar, otherwise the 3-dots dropdown menu is not displayed. Why? How can I force the display of the menu to leaving aside whether the device is or is not in possession of the key hardware ?

Comment: what is your min sdk version?

Comment: my min sdk version is 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overflow menu (3 dot) [not shown by design](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/compatibility.html) on devices with hardware menu button.

This is correct behaviour. Yom must not force it to show or mimic in any way.

> Android phones with traditional navigation hardware keys don't display
>   the virtual navigation bar at the bottom of the screen. Instead, the
>   action overflow is available from the menu hardware key.

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">

 <item
  android:id="@+id/action_settings"
  android:title="@string/action_settings"
  android:orderInCategory="100"
  android:icon="@drawable/menu_icon"
  app:showAsAction="always">
  <menu>
    <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings1"
    android:title="@string/action_settings1"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
     />
  <item
    android:id="@+id/action_credits"
    android:title="@string/action_credits"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    />
  <item android:title="@string/action_project"
        android:id="@+id/action_project"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    />
  </menu>
</item>
</menu>
```